# Uncaught ReferenceError: emailjs is not defined at HTMLFormElement.onsubmit

Tags: javascript, angular, email, onsubmit

I'm trying to use Emailjs as client side script to send email. But am getting the error as "Uncaught ReferenceError: emailjs is not defined
    at HTMLFormElement.onsubmit".

Please find the below html code.

```
<form id="myform" onsubmit="emailjs.sendForm('default_service', 'XXXXXX', this); return false;"  method="post">
  <label>reply_to</label>
  <input type="text" name="reply_to" />
  <label>from_name</label>
  <input type="text" name="from_name" />
  <label>to_name</label>
  <input type="text" name="to_name" />
  <label>message_html</label>
  <input type="text" name="message_html" />
  <br><br>
  <button>
    Send
  </button>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.emailjs.com/sdk/2.2.4/email.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
   (function(){
      emailjs.init("user_ABC");
   })();
</script>
```

Please help on this!

Comment: Is this angular 2+ or anuglarJS?

Answer (score 1):

You included the emailjs CDN after calling the emailjs object, so you're basically trying to use something you haven't defined yet. Moving the emailjs CDN to the beginning of your head should fix it.